# Calculating Seconds Until a Given Date and Time in Joda Time

Tags: scala, akka, jodatime

I am trying to use the Joda Time library to help me schedule sending some messages to an Actor in Akka.

I would like to schedule sending emails every day at 8:30 AM. To do this, I have to tell the scheduler how many seconds (or milliseconds) to wait until the next message is sent.

I would like to account for daylight savings (to make sure it always fires around 8:30, and not 7:30 or 9:30) so I will use `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`.

So, basically, I have:

`targetDate = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1)` and `targetTime = new LocalTime(8, 30)`

and

`rightNow = LocalDateTime.now()`

I was wondering what is the best way to compose a `targetDateTime` based on `targetDate` and `targetTime` so I can use it to compute the time difference with `rightNow`

I know I can create a new `LocalDateTime` extracting all the values for the constructor from my `targetDate` and `targetTime` but: is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I have settled for:

`targetDateTime = targetDate.toLocalDateTime(targetTime)`

`secondsToWait = Seconds.secondsBetween(rightNow, targetDateTime)`

Comment: You might be interested in [scala-time](https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time)

Answer (score 0):

Getting targetDateTime is easy if you have the `targetDate` and `targetTime` (as given in your question) :

```
targetDateTime = targetDate.toDateTime(targetTime);
```

Getting the seconds of the `Duration` between now and `targetDateTime`:

```
new Duration(new DateTime(), targetDateTime).getStandardSeconds();
```

The method is called standard seconds because it assumes every second to be a standard second of 1000 milliseconds. As its javadoc says, currently all Chronologies only have standard seconds.

But you can also simply use milliseconds (no conversion assumptions needed) :

```
new Duration(new DateTime(), targetDateTime).getMillis();
```

*Disclaimer : I only just saw this was a scala question, so you may have to correct for any syntax differences, since I'm not versed in scala.*